# Jetson Nano with 64 Ubuntu running 32bit Python app

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a jetson nano that runs 64 Ubuntu. I need to run 32bit app of python3.5.
One solution is to install 32bit python version
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get install python3.5.1`
but it doesnot work. Ofcourse I have already installed the libraries for i386.

Another idea was to run i386/ubuntu image but a message appears about architecture incompatibility when running.

````
   sudo docker run -it i386/ubuntu```


Finally is it possible to run 32bit docker ubuntu image on Ubuntu 64bit on jetson?
````

Answer (score 1):

The Jetson Nano's CPU instruction set is armv8 (or arm64 or arch64), while `i386` means x86. these are incompatible instruction sets. So there is no way to run i386 applications natively on the Jetson Nano. Maybe a virtual machine can help.